# Manipulating Nested JSON Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i have bellow json array

```
var rowdataarray = [
                     {
                      "products": "Cars",
                      "solddate" : "2022-01-01",
                      "noofitems" : "7"
                     },
                     {
                      "products": "books",
                      "solddate" : "2022-01-01",
                      "noofitems" : "10"
                     },
                     {
                      "products": "Cars",
                      "solddate" : "2022-01-02",
                      "noofitems" : "2"
                     },
                     {
                      "products": "Table",
                      "solddate" : "2022-01-02",
                      "noofitems" : "5"
                     }
                   ];
```

and then have category array

```
const category = ["Cars","books","Table"]
```

based on these two array trying to create new array which will give me each day for each product how many items sold. above category must follow when creating data array. if the product is not sold on that day then it should insert as 0.

array expecting

```
var finalarray = [{
        date: '2022-01-01',
        data: [7,10,0]
    }, {
        date: '2022-01-02',
        data: [2,0,5]
    }]
```

bellow code written not able to contiunue forward

```
 $.when(
 $.each(category , function (key, val) {

        $.each(rowdataarray , function (key, x) {
    
                if(x.products == val){
                    finalarray .push({
                        "date" : x.solddate,
                        "data" : [x.noofitems]
                    })
                }
        })
 })
 ).then(function () {
    console.log(test)     
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Collect the data by date and associate each count by product
2. Map over the entries and query each for your `category`

```js
var rowdataarray = [{"products":"Cars","solddate":"2022-01-01","noofitems":"7"},{"products":"books","solddate":"2022-01-01","noofitems":"10"},{"products":"Cars","solddate":"2022-01-02","noofitems":"2"},{"products":"Table","solddate":"2022-01-02","noofitems":"5"}]
const category = ["Cars","books","Table"]

const byDate = rowdataarray.reduce((m, {
  solddate: d, 
  products: p, 
  noofitems: c
}) => ({
  ...m,
  [ d ]: { // the date is the top-level key
    ...m[d],
    [ p ]: (m[d]?.[p] ?? 0) + parseFloat(c) // add the count to any existing product count
  }
}), {})
console.log("byDate", byDate)

const finalarray = Object.entries(byDate).map(([ date, counts ]) => ({
  date,
  data: category.map(cat => counts[cat] ?? 0)
}))

console.info("finalarray", finalarray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: this is brilliant. let me go through and understand this now. thanks

Comment: I know it's a bit of an ASCII salad. Let me know if anything needs clarification